# Como resolver sobreposição de personagens (sprites) na tela com PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo TOP-DOWN com vários inimigos, porém, devido a ordem em que eles são plotados na tela, não importa se um está atrás do outro, sempre aquele que foi plotado por último vai ter seu sprite desenhado por cima dos outros.

Gostaria de saber se existe uma espécie de terceiro eixo além do X e Y, para que eu possa ajustar no caso de que quanto mais ao sul o inimigo estiver, significa que mais próximo ele está, e consequentemente, o sprite deve ficar acima dos demais, assim como quanto mais ao norte, mais longe estará e seu sprite deve ficar por baixo dos outros.

Segue trecho no qual através de um loop crio 20 instâncias da classe Inimigos.

```
i = 0
waves = 0
enemies = []
for x in range(20):
      inimigo = "e"+str(i)
      inimigo = Inimigo(player)
      enemies.append(inimigo)
      i += 1
```

E abaixo segue trecho que uso dentro do "While True" do game:

```
  for e in enemies:
        e.draw()
```

Acho que devido ao trecho acima, os inimigos são plotados de forma totalmente independente um do outro. Então eles não têm "consciência" um do outro, e acabam tendo os sprites sobrescritos pelos que foram desenhados por último.

O que eu preciso, é que haja uma maneira de controlar a profundidade da tela, de forma que independentemente da ordem em que foram desenhados, aquele que estiver mais ao sul esteja na frente.

Espero ter explicado direito.

A execução do jogo pode ser visto em https://www.instagram.com/p/B7j37-Bh_Jn/ e o código completo está em https://github.com/Nathanbahia/Exemplo-Pygame

Comment: Uma das classes espcializadas de Group do Pygame permite um controle assim - mas sem você colocar um exemplo mínimo e funcionando de como está seu código, ninguém vai responder - já que teria que escrever todo um programa do zero só pra demonstrar isso.

Comment: Em outras palavras: por favor edite a questão e inclua um exemplo mínimo e completo (que funcione sozinho) de como está, ou a pergunta vai ser fechada.

Answer (score 1):

```
def desenharSobre(sobreposicao, character, terrp, pos_x, pos_y):
    if sobreposicao == True:
        screen.blit(spritesCenario['home'], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(terrp, (100, 100))
        screen.blit(character, (pos_x, pos_y))
    else:
        screen.blit(spritesCenario['home'], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(character, (pos_x, pos_y))
        screen.blit(terrp, (100, 100))

def sobreposicao(pos_x, pos_y):
    for i in range(100, 165):
        if pos_x == 100 and pos_y == i:
            return True
    return False
```

e antes do update ou flip no laço principal você coloca:

```
desenharSobre(sobreposicao(pos_x, pos_y), character, terrp, pos_x, pos_y)
```

pos_x e pos_y é o x e y do personagem

character é o personagem controlavel

terrp o personagem nao controlavel

o range é ate em que posição em y que o personagem controlavel se sobrepoem ao outro

Answer (score 0):

Ah - com código fica mais fácil. Apesar de estar incompleto.

A classe `Inimigo` deve herdar de `pygame.sprite.Sprite`, e em vez de uma lista comum, você deve adicionar os `Inimigo` num grupo - uma classe derivada de `pygame.Sprite.Group` - mas no caso,  use especificamente a classe `LayeredUpdates` (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates )

Se todo o restante estiver certinho, quando você chamar o método `draw` do grupo (e não de cada sprite separadamente), ele vai desenhar em ordem.  Se não for a ordem desejada, esse grupo permite você trocar os sprites de "layers" e você vai ter o controle desejado.

Comment: Arrumei o link, desculpe-me. E muito obrigado pela ajuda.